# MYSQL Sum Union - правильный запрос

Tags: mysql

Искал как реализовать объединение сумм int полей разных таблиц и нашёл данный ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387773/6763536 всё работает но просто не могу понять что это за символ `x` в конце запроса без которого mysql возвращает ошибку и зачем он нужен?

Comment: У подзапроса должно быть имя, по которому к нему можно обращаться. Вот 'x' это и есть это имя

Comment: алиас он еще называется